# Why "a" before "elements of a first step"?

Tags: grammar

I have learned that "the first" is a determiner. So this example arises a question for me.

> Elements of a first step

Could someone explain it?
[For context](http://edition.cnn.com/2013/11/24/world/meast/iran-deal-text/index.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use "a first step" to convey the idea that there may be other options for "first step", and that what is being offered is just one of them.  "the first step" would be used if a set of steps has already been identified.